# Is there a way to bypass the Steam region lock?

Tags: steam, region-lock

I want to check out a game but when I view it from Steam, it says:

"This item is currently unavailable in your region"

Is there a way to go around this limitation? Not simply by using a proxy to view the website but to actually get the game and play it?

Comment: If you proxy your internet connection, and have a means of payment that is registered to an address in the target country, you should be able to buy the game.

Comment: Will something like Tunnelbear work?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and safest way to get a game that is unavailable in your region is to have somebody else buy it for you, there is a myriad ways to wire the money to them. The only exceptions are some (but not all) games that are unavailable due to censorship in your country, so look out for that if you live in Germany, Australia or another country with similarly ridiculous censorship laws.

Comment: What if the game is free-to-play?

Comment: Then this solution won't work for you. Out of interest, do you have a particular game and country in mind?

Comment: Sure thing, [Ragnarok Online 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/231060/) and Philippines. I ran Tunnelbear and I can view the game store page. But when I start up Steam client, it won't connect to the internet if Tunnelbear is running.

Comment: I would suggest trying another VPN provider, apparently some have problems with Steam (or maybe it's the other way around) while others do not.

Answer (score -3):

1. Open Steam Client
2. Press Steam Top Left
3. Press Settings
4. Change Your Region In Download Region
   You Can Bypass The Region Lock And Once You Installed It You Can Change The Region Again

Hope I Helped

Comment: -1 **Incorrect** | Your download region only determines where the files are downloaded from. Your store settings (which dictate which version of the game you get) is determined by your account settings, and all download regions cache the different versions of each game (if there are ROW and non-ROW versions).